# Spring boot でデータベースをマイグレーションできない

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Spring bootでモデル定義を行い`gradle build`コマンドでビルドしようとしましたが下記エラーによりできません。

エラー

```
> Building 81% > :testERROR:  relation "point" does not exist
STATEMENT:  alter table point drop constraint FK_i94b2uy0ud0q6jrkb41sqjlrg
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 13
STATEMENT:  alter table user drop constraint FK_1mcjtpxmwom9h9bf2q0k412e0
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group" at character 22
STATEMENT:  drop table if exists group cascade
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 22
STATEMENT:  drop table if exists user cascade
ERROR:  sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
STATEMENT:  drop sequence hibernate_sequence
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group" at character 14
STATEMENT:  create table group (id int8 not null, dominate_point int8, player_count int8, primary key (id))
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 14
STATEMENT:  create table user (id int8 not null, consumer_key varchar(255) not null, provider int4 not null, uid varchar(255) not null, profile_id int8, primary key (id))
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 13
STATEMENT:  alter table user add constraint UK_c77nknup654c0jv25o6if51vr unique (consumer_key)
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 13
STATEMENT:  alter table user add constraint FK_1mcjtpxmwom9h9bf2q0k412e0 foreign key (profile_id) references profile
:test
2015-10-28 21:14:50.121  INFO 3555 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@457e0562: startup date [Wed Oct 28 21:14:45 JST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-28 21:14:50.130  INFO 3555 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-10-28 21:14:50.130  INFO 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table point drop constraint FK_i94b2uy0ud0q6jrkb41sqjlrg
> Building 81% > :test > 1 test completedERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 13
STATEMENT:  alter table user drop constraint FK_1mcjtpxmwom9h9bf2q0k412e0
Hibernate: alter table user drop constraint FK_1mcjtpxmwom9h9bf2q0k412e0
2015-10-28 21:14:50.134 ERROR 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user drop constraint FK_1mcjtpxmwom9h9bf2q0k412e0
2015-10-28 21:14:50.135 ERROR 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  ポジション: 13
Hibernate: drop table if exists group cascade
> Building 81% > :test > 1 test completedERROR:  syntax error at or near "group" at character 22
STATEMENT:  drop table if exists group cascade
2015-10-28 21:14:50.136 ERROR 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists group cascade
2015-10-28 21:14:50.136 ERROR 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"
  ポジション: 22
Hibernate: drop table if exists point cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists profile cascade
> Building 81% > :test > 1 test completedERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 22
STATEMENT:  drop table if exists user cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists user cascade
2015-10-28 21:14:50.147 ERROR 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user cascade
2015-10-28 21:14:50.147 ERROR 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  ポジション: 22
Hibernate: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
2015-10-28 21:14:50.155  INFO 3555 --- [       Thread-4] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

エラーが起きたモデルの定義は下記のとおりです。

userテーブル

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;


@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "uid", nullable = false)
    private String uid;

    @Column(name = "provider", nullable = false)
    private Providers provider;

    @Column(name = "consumer_key", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String consumerKey;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Profile profile;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public String getConsumerKey() {
        return consumerKey;
    }

    public void setConsumerKey(String consumerKey) {
        this.consumerKey = consumerKey;
    }

    public User(Providers provider){
        this.provider=provider;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public Providers getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(Providers provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

groupテーブル

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "player_count")
    private Long playerCount;

    @Column(name = "dominate_point")
    private Long dominatePoint;



    public Group() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getPlayerCount() {
        return playerCount;
    }

    public void setPlayerCount(Long playerCount) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
    }

    public Long getDominatePoint() {
        return dominatePoint;
    }

    public void setDominatePoint(Long dominatePoint) {
        this.dominatePoint = dominatePoint;
    }


}
```

pointテーブル

```
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

@Entity
public class Point {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private float latitude;

    @Column(name = "longtitude")
    private float longtitude;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupId;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @ManyToOne
    private Profile profile;



    public Point() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongtitude() {
        return longtitude;
    }

    public void setLongtitude(float longtitude) {
        this.longtitude = longtitude;
    }

    public Long getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Long groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }


}
```

エラーを見るとマイグレーションに失敗しているように見えるのですが、何が間違っているのかわかりません。アドバイスをお願いします。
データベースはPostgresqlを使っています。データベースは作成済みです。

Comment: `user` や `group` という名前は PostgreSQL では識別子として扱われますので、テーブル名などには使用することができません(`CREATE USER ...` とか `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...`)。できれば `users` や `groups` などという名前に変更することをお勧めします。

Comment: @argus  コメントありがとう御座います。エラーは消えてコンパイルできました。しかし`psql`,`\d`でデータベースを観てみるとテーブルが表示されません。これは成功しているのでしょうか。

Comment: psql で接続しているデータベースは Spring Boot 用に作成したデータベースでしょうか？ もしかすると別のデータベースにログインしているとかはありませんか？ ご存知かもしれませんが、`\l` でデータベース名などを確認する事ができます。

Comment: すみません。解決しました。設定ファイルの`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`が`create-drop`になっていたので、セッションが終わるとテーブルを削除する設定になっていました。

Comment: こちら、 users/groups を用いることで問題は解決されているのでしょうか。もしそうであるならば、[自己回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1747/754) をお願いできますでしょうか。 (community Wiki で回答してしまおうにも、果たして本当にこれで解決しているのか、自分にはわからないので。。)